# Ubuntu laptop extremely slow when charging

Tags: power-management, battery

I have a HP laptop and something very awkward is happening.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04.
When the laptop is working on battery, everything is fine and the laptop works fantastic. But, when I plug in the charger, the laptop becomes so slow that is unusable.

What I have tried so far:
Attempt 1 (Unsuccessful): I changed my processor to performance mode with the command:
`echo performance | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`
This didn't help.

Attempt 2 (Unsuccessful): I created a file `/etc/modprobe.d/local.conf` and added the following line:
`options drm_kms_helper poll=N` 
This also didn't help.

Attempt 3 (Unsuccessful): I edited the file `gedit /etc/default/grub` and added here
`drm_kms_helper.poll=N` as the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX parameter`.
This also did not work.

I am sorry if this is a very stupid question but this is very frustrating.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check out https://www.pcwebopaedia.com/laptops/info/laptop-lags-when-plugged-in-charging/ for a possible answer. Solution does not appear to be available, I will research it.

Comment: I found a potential solution. Try installing an app called CPULimit by running `apt-get install cpulimit` See https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-limit-cpu-usage-with-cpulimit-on-ubuntu-linux for more information.

Comment: Update UEFI before anything else.

Answer (score -1):

Some laptops intentionally slow down when they are running on battery in order to conserve power. The processor (CPU) in the laptop switches to a slower speed, and processors use less power when running slower, so the battery should last longer.

Comment: Your answer is the reverse of the question asked. Read the question again, it is slow when not on battery.

Comment: Hello Jacob. I appreciate the fact that you are trying to help.
Unfortunately, the problem I have is that the laptop is slow when it is charging. When it is working on battery it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad.

Comment: His answer is on par with the why. I am struggling with the same thing right now on an Alienware M17R5. If I let the battery dip down to the low digits and plug it in, it should give me a decent amount of power and charge simultaneously, especially since it's like a 338-watt charger. In my case, though; it won't stop throttling until it hits around 80%.